# Jekyll Liquid : does post_url accept variable?

Tags: jekyll, liquid

this works fine:

```
{% post_url 2017-06-14-Home %}
```

but this doesn't:

```
{% assign mypost = '2017-06-14-Home' %}
{% post_url {{mypost}} %}
```

Why? This seems to be pretty straightforward...

**EDIT**

OK, so finally I ported my site to Pelican. Now it works just fine.

Comment: Did you try `{% post_url mypost %}`?

Comment: yes, of course :-)

Answer (score 0):

That is weird. I think it is because in, `{% post_url 2017-06-14-Home %}` '2017-06-14-Home' is not a string. It seems like it should be but it's probably actually an object.

Not sure if this will work but try the following:

```
{% assign mypost = 2017-06-14-Home %}
{% post_url mypost %}
```

Comment: Where did you note this above? I am not talking about the omission of the curly braces. I am talking about the omission of the quote marks.

Comment: Oh, OK. You are right. I see it now. But this doesn't work either :-(

Comment: What a strange issue. I'll take another look later try and replicate myself.